# IE 8 security settings prevents javascript to send xmlHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest

I am facing problem that whenever I turn off security settings in IE8, in my application, xmlHTTPRequest call is failed.However when I turn it on, its working fine.
The security feature is : Tools -> Internet Options -> Advance -> security -> Enable Native xmlHTTP support.
If it is checked then no problem occurs but in case if it is not checked, the xmlHTTPReq fails to send request to server.(I don't see the cgi call in debugger window).

So my question is : is it possible to detect that this security settings is enabled or not using JavaScript programatically  ?

My code for cgi call is as under :

```
try{
        var xmlHttpReq;
        var destinationURL = cgiBinPath+"helloworld.cgi?start";
        // IE 7+, Mozilla/Safari
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlHttpReq=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        //IE 5,6
        else {
            xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 0){
            xmlHttpReq.open('GET', destinationURL, true);
            xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4){
                  //Control never reaches here
                }
            }               
            xmlHttpReq.send();
        }
    }catch(e){
        alert('Exception '+e);
    }
```

Comment: No sane person disables this setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article about native XMLHTTP on MSDN. It also provides a solution for your problem.

**Edit**
I'm sorry, I didn't read the article carefully enough... [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2006/07/03/IE7-and-native-XMLHttp-support.aspx) one will answer your question. You will have to try if you can create an instance of the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    try {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (ex) {
        xmlHttpReq = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
} else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...
I have already studied this article but I think nothing is there which may help me to detect that particular security feature is enabled or not...

Comment: Thanks again...!!!

I will try this one and will let you know if it resolves my issue..

Just one thing to clarify that what if I write directly in catch block like this :-

 xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
(without "window") Does it make any difference with your answer ??

Comment: It's just the detailed form of "take the `ActiveXObject` object from the global scope". Your shortened version will do the same.